# Setting Click Function For Elements From Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach

I have an object that has keys and values as arrays. I tried to write a function and set up click function to each of them at once on document ready.

```
var settingsItems = {
    'featured': [
        'featured-1-heading',
        'featured-1-desc',
        'featured-2-heading',
        'featured-2-desc',
        'featured-3-heading',
        'featured-3-desc'
    ],
    'greeting': [
        'greeting-1-inputField',
        'greeting-2-inputField'
    ]
}
```

This is how my array looks like. And this is what I call in document ready:

```
for (var group in settingsItems) {
    settingsItems[group].forEach(function(x) {
        jQuery('#' + x).click(function () {
            switch (group) {
                case 'greeting':
                    var element = greetingForm
                    break;
                case 'featured':
                    var element = featuredForm
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("default alert");
            }
            settingsIconClicked(element, true, group)
        })
    })
}
```

To me, it should've worked but it is always returning 'greeting' as `group` variable, even when I click `featured`'s elements.

Comment: You need a closure as when the `click` event occurs the loop has finished, therefore `group` contains the last value of the array. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information

Comment: I checked the top answers last example. He's using numbers and storing them in an array as far as I understand. However, I couldn't figure out how exactly to apply this in my case. Can I kindly ask you to add an answer below, to help me figure it out

Comment: Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/24dmpLxn/. Note that I made some of the variables in to strings as they were missing from your sample above. Also note that this would be made much, *much* simpler if you just put a class on all the relevant elements and didn't bother with the loop or lookup object.

Comment: Here's a version which uses the simpler class method I mentioned: https://jsfiddle.net/24dmpLxn/1/

Comment: Huge thanks man! Nice tips. You saved me hours. Have a good day